# Rewrite rule using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Hi I basically want to change this:

```
http://domain.com/image_shower.php?image=i/test
```

into this:

```
http://domain.com/i/test
```

Thanks for you help in advance.

or if that's impossible because it will search for a directory then just like the image_shower/test without the .php.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^i/(.*)$ image_shower.php?image=i/$1 [QSA,L]
```